# Strapi GraphQL disable user confirm validation

Tags: graphql, strapi, user-permissions

I am new to Strapi. I enabled Graphql services for my Strapi applications. When I try to access data through GraphQL API, I want to disable the User Confirmation validation. I commented out the following code in the `/node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/config/policies/permissions.js`

```
// if (
    //   _.get(await store.get({ key: 'advanced' }), 'email_confirmation') &&
    //   !ctx.state.user.confirmed
    // ) {
    //   return handleErrors(ctx, 'Your account email is not confirmed.', 'unauthorized');
    // }
```

After I comment it out, I can disable the validation. But I knew it would not work in production. Is there any way to do this in the Strapi Admin pages (or) any customization available at the code level?